# 351 ERROR: No matching distribution found for distro-info==1.1+ubuntu0.1

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, channel

i am new to docker,
i am using a docker project where i am trying to make a docker compose build and i am receiving an error as
351 ERROR: No matching distribution found for distro-info==1.1+ubuntu0.1 but in my requirements.txt
distro-info==1.1+ubuntu0.1 this is defined

but previously it was working, but when i put the command pip freeze > requirements.txt and added channels to the file after that i am trying to build it again it is showing me some errors and one of the error is this 351 error